# Which Purana describes Jatila and her seven husbands

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43418/were-puranas-extant-during-mahabharata), its quoted that:

> I have heard in the Purana that a lady of name Jatila, the foremost of all virtuous women belonging to the race of Gotama had married seven Rishis.

Question is, which Purana describes Jatila and her seven husbands?